# Renaming multiple files with same filename but different extensions

Tags: windows, powershell, rename

I have 180 files in a folder all with the SAME filename but 180 DIFFERENT extensions. I want them all to be .jpg. I cannot seem to make windows or dos or powershell work to rename all files to a filename.jpg. I think because it recognizes it as 180 different files since the extensions are different. so renaming them doesn't result in windows adding the (1), (2), (3) etc to the filenames. It simply adds a (1) to ALL of the files and keeps the different extensions. Thank you for any help...

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

```
$i=1
Get-ChildItem | ForEach {

        Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("filename" + $i + ".jpg")
        $i++

}
```

Results:

```
filename1.jpg
filename2.jpg
filename3.jpg
...
```