# rename file with different extension

Tags: windows-10, batch, rename

Everyday I have to rename 6 files todaydate.94E and todaydate.94N in txt file and then I have to merge every file.

The example would be:

26/02/2020.94E

26/02/2020 (1).94E

26/02/2020 (2).94E

26/02/2020.94N

26/02/2020 (1).94N

26/02/2020 (2).94N

So, I created this batch to rename and then merge them.

```
if exist *.94* (
ren *.94* *.txt 
)

if not exist all.txt (
copy *.txt all.txt
) else (

del all.txt
copy *.txt all.txt
)
```

It work fine except that there is a conflict between the name .94E and .94N

> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

even if I do this :

```
if exist *.94E (
ren *.94E *.txt 
)
if exist *.94N (
ren *.94N *.txt 
)
```

I saw this [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/1260416/how-to-rename-multiple-files-with-same-name-and-different-extensions) but I don't know why none of this codes work with me. 
For info, system is windows 10 and I am not a user admin.

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `ren *.94* *.txt` will try to rename all matching files and change their extension to `.txt`.

So what happens first is that `16022020.94e` is renamed to `16022020.txt`.

Then, an attempt is made to rename `16022020.94n` to `16022020.txt` too, but that file already exists so the operation fails.

You second piece of code (after *even if I do this*) will fail in the same way.

Renaming all files to `.txt` is not possible because of the filename conflicts, but you *can* merge these files by simply using `copy *.94? all.txt`.

BTW, I assume you gave us made-up filenames (filenames on Windows can't contain a `/` character); if they are real, you may have other problems.

Comment: Your are right it is a space not a "/" and your solution works perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, you could use:

```
gci -FIle | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + $_.Extension.Substring(1) + '.txt' }
```

```
   Directory: C:\Users\keith\Sandbox\bat file


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (1).94E
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (1).94N
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (2).94E
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (2).94N
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020.94E
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020.94N


PS C:\...\bat file>gci -FIle | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + $_.Extension.Substring(1) + '.txt' }                                                                                                     PS C:\...\bat file>gci                                                                                

    Directory: C:\Users\keith\Sandbox\bat file


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (1)94E.txt
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (1)94N.txt
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (2)94E.txt
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-2020 (2)94N.txt
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-202094E.txt
-a----        2/26/2020   1:49 PM              0 26-02-202094N.txt
```

and automate your merge as well.

Comment: ok thank you but this also rename the .ps1, I will check how to execute it in another directory

Comment: Just add a `Path` parameter with the path to your text files:`gci -Path 'c:\Data' -FIle | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + $_.Extension.Substring(1) + '.txt' }`

Comment: Or you could filter `Get-CHildItem` to exclude `.ps1` files, but I wouldn't think it good practice to keep scripts in a data directory.